# ValueError for comparison of np.arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of lists of np.arrays, representing islands > island > geodesic point on the island.

I'm trying to use:

```
if not groups:
    createNewGroup(point)
else:
    for group in groups:
        if point in group:
            continue
    else:
        createNewGroup(point)
```

The first island is being created correctly, but for the second island I am getting this error:

```
File "A2.py", line 371, in findIslands
if point in group:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than 
one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I've researched this error and am trying to understand how this applies to my situation, and have tried applying `.any()` and `.all()` to `point` but I am getting the same error regardless.

I'm trying to check if the current geodesic point is already in the list of lists for any of the islands.  Point is multidimensional and I think that's where the issue is coming from.

Comment: Can you show an detailed example of your data structure?

Answer (score 0):

This error arises when a boolean array is used in a scalar context, such as an `if` statement.  Or maybe in the  `in` part of the expression.

Is `point` an array, and `group` a list of arrays?

In general `in` is not a good test when working with arrays.

To get more help print `point`, `group`, `point in group`.  Or at least their type, shape and dtype.

Make a small list of `point`, and focus on to perform an `in` test or equivalent.  How do you tell whether one equals another?  `point1 == point2`?